Making a URL Router in Avalonia C#
Im trying to make a URL router for avalonia. I want this strictly for the browser. I want it to handle URL requests as it should. For example if the user acceses my website like this: https://example.com/somepage then load SomePage.axaml, else if it empty ( https://example.com ) to load MainView.axaml
I tryied to make my own router, but i cant figure a way to get the current URL. This is what is a class i made:
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;
using TestApplication;
using TestApplication.Views;

public class Router
{
    private readonly ContentControl _contentControl;

    public Router(ContentControl contentControl)
    {
        _contentControl = contentControl;
    }

    public void Navigate(string path)
    {
        UserControl view;

        switch (path)
        {
            case "":
            case "/":
                view = new MainView();
                break;
            case "/test":
                view = new testView();
                break;
            default:
                view = new notfound();
                break;
        }

        _contentControl.Content = view;
    }
}

and this is how i use that:
using Avalonia.Controls;
using System;

namespace TestApplication.Views;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Router _router;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _router = new Router(this.FindControl<ContentControl>("MainContent"));

        // Assuming you have a method to get the current URL path
        var path = GetPathFromUrl();
        _router.Navigate(path);
    }

    private string GetPathFromUrl()
    {
        string simulatedUrl = "https://example.com/hi";
        Uri uri = new Uri(simulatedUrl);
        return uri.AbsolutePath;
    }
}

i cant make a working GetPathFromUrl, and i couldent find anything else related on the internet..
